# CORS response on express js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, cors, header

Facing error as Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/save-comment' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

But facing for only few API not for all
check code for reference

```
async addComment(postId) {
      const post = this.posts.find(post => post.id === postId);
      console.log(post.newComment);
        await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/save-comment', {
          postId,
          comment: post.newComment,
        })
          .then(response => {
            this.fetchLatestPost();
            // Handle success if needed
            console.log('Comment saved successfully:', response.data);

            // Clear the comment text box after adding the comment
            // post.comments.push(post.newComment);
            post.newComment = '';
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Handle error if needed
            console.error('Error saving the comment:', error);
          });
    }
```

In api.js I have

```
router.post('/save-comment', (req, res) => {
  const { postId, comment } = req.body;
  
  const query = 'INSERT INTO comments (post_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?)';

  connection.query(query, [postId, comment], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error saving the comment:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while saving the comment' });
    } else {
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Comment saved successfully' });
    }
  });
});
```

I have also added

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("access-control-allow-origin", "*");
  res.header("access-control-allow-methods","GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
  res.header("access-control-allow-headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Express.js has [a CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html). You should use it instead of manually implementing CORS.

Comment: Second the above. And in the config for that middleware you need to set localhost:8080 as an allowed origin